# iOS: How to add constraints for textfield in a table cell in code

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint

I use Xcode5, iOS SDK 7.

I create a `UITextField` in a table cell in code, not in storyboard. I want the width of textField should always be same as the width of the cell, but I don't know how achieve it.

I know I should use `NSLayoutConstraint`, but I can't find a tutorial, and I have tried in my way, they all can't work....

Could anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

The snippet of code:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame: cell.contentView.frame];
[cell addSubview:textField];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Renish Dadhaniya 's answer, I figured it out:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame: cell.contentView.frame];
[cell addSubview:textField];

[textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSLayoutConstraint *textLeftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: textField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];

NSLayoutConstraint *textRightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: textField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:0.f];

[cell addConstraint:textLeftConstraint];
[cell addConstraint:textRightConstraint];
```

It works well!!

Answer (score 1):

Below link for Autolayout.

[1. Auto layout in iOS6 adding constraints through code](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/auto-layout-in-ios-6-adding-constraints-through-code)
[2. iOS auto layouts](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_auto_layouts.htm)
[3. Auto layout for iOS revisited](http://www.adevelopingstory.com/blog/2013/05/auto-layout-for-ios-revisited.html)
[4. Beginning auto layout tutorial in iOS7](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7)